# SSRS report is not loading for huge number of records

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a SSRS report. Some time the number of records for this report will be more than 500 000. The procedure to execute for the report takes less than 50 seconds. At that time when i execute the report it will show loading and after some time the loading symbol is go and nothing will show. Up to 300k records it is working fine.

Comment: After how many minutes does the loading symbol disappear?

Comment: It sound like you are getting an http timeout either in the ssrs api or the client application. The ssrs log files will probably shed more light on where the error occurs.

Comment: Yes, It is due to time out. So this is occurring due to number of records. Is there any limitation for number of records in SSRS ?